# react-router-dom does not display component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to display my 'Home' component in my React project via react-router-dom. Thought I got your tone done right, I don't have a compile time error but the Home component just doesn't show up. Do you have an idea  ?

App.js :

```
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route pathname="/" element={<Home />}> </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js :

```
import React from "react";
import banner from "../assets/banner.jpg";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../Styles/Home.css';

function Home(){
    return (
        <div className="home" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${banner})` }}>
            <div className="headerContainer">
                <h1>Food Corner</h1>
                <p>AMERICAN FOOD AT A CLICK.</p>
                <Link> 
                <button> Order Now </button>
                 </Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: What version of react router are you using, and are you certain that you are actually viewing the `/` route?

Comment: React Router v 6.1.1
The url is well "http://localhost:3000/"

Answer (score 1):

If this is Router Router v6 (assuming since you are using `<Routes>...</Routes>`), the prop name is "path" and not "pathname"

So this:

```
<Route pathname="/" element={<Home />}> </Route>
```

Should be this:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />}> </Route>
```

Here are the docs for React-Router-Dom v6 (which is different than the v5 docs): [Here](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/basic)

You should also change your react-router-dom imports. You should import BrowserRouter as Router like:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but your solution does not work. By applying your solution I have this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
"'

Comment: @ThéoRousseau You need to change all of your "pathname" to just "path".

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple minor issues:

1. The `Route` component uses a `path` prop, not a `pathname` prop. With no `path` prop there is no matching path and `Home` is not rendered.

   ```
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   ```
2. The `Link` is missing what it's linking to, i.e. it is missing the `to` prop. This causes a `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')` error. Add the `to` prop link destination. Example:

   ```
   <Link to="/order">
     <button> Order Now </button>
   </Link>
   ```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-does-not-display-component]